# How to make image in double to be greyscale

Tags: matlab, image-processing, double

I'll do the medical image processing with CLAHE method (I use the code in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22182-contrast-limited-adaptive-histogram-equalization-clahe/all_files ) and region growing ( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19084-region-growing/content/regiongrowing.m )

that function can run if i use double data type for image. but converting image to double make its to be the binary image.

anyone know how to make image still in double but not to be a binary image?

Answer (score 1):

If your image is `img` then do `im2double(img)`. See [im2double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2double.html) on the mathworks reference site.

Comment: i've do those. but image always be a binary (0 1)

Comment: When my image is a file do:
`im = imread ('PATH_TO_FILE');`
If it's not a file but an in memory buffer, let's assume it's called `im`.

Then if it's RGB do
`im2double (rgb2gray (im))`
If it's simply gray do nothing.

It's a bit hard to help more without seeing the code that loads your image or creates it. The procedure above works perfectly for me...

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your comment correctly, you're trying to convert a binary image to a gray scale image. If so, this is not possible, as you've thrown away all the intensity information in lieu of a simple `0/1` image.

If your question was on how to convert a color/grayscale image to double, then [LightningIsMyName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167009/how-to-make-image-in-double-to-be-greyscale/6167906#6167906) has the answer for you. Here's a small example that you can play around with to see what you really want:

```
img=imread('peppers.png');       %#read in MATLAB's stock image
imgDouble=im2double(img);        %#convert uint8 to double
imgGray=rgb2gray(img);           %#convert RGB image to grayscale
imgGrayDouble=im2double(imgGray);%#convert grayscale image to double.
```

Here's how your color and grayscale images should look like:
[image]